# How many ways are there to wrap the Tefillin Shel Yad?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, tefilin

Can you guys please lists all the ways that the Tefillin Shel Yad can/are wrapped, because I think there was more than 10 ways how to wrap it. And could guys (if you can) explain the origins of each one? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean wrapping it on the arm or how to wrap it around the box when done? If the arm, are you including Nusach Ashkenaz vs. Sefarad versions?

Comment: start with this, pages 632-639 http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=632

Comment: @Danno I think OP means how to wrap it on the arm, not how to make the knot.

Comment: @DanF that's in there as well

Comment: Hi Ploni ben Almoni tzedek! I posted an answer to your question. I assumed you meant the many methods of wrapping the tefillin shel yad around your hand.